# JAVA - Create a formatted table in excel (.csv) from lists

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, printwriter, read-write

I have a algorithm written in java (too long to post here) that translates a list of numbers into a excel csv document.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        SimulationSystem myObj = new SimulationSystem();
        List<Integer> sys1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

then this bit:

```
        myObj.SystemAnalysis(1,20,20);
        sys1.add(average);
```

is repeated many times with different numbers and I want these numbers to be the y and x of the table. Example:

```
| |20|40|80|160|
20|
40|  **with the answers in here**
80|
160|
```

```
        System.out.println(sys1);
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("outNumbers.csv"));
        sys1.stream().forEach(i->outFile.print(i + ", "));
        sys2.stream().forEach(i->outFile.print(i + ", "));
        outFile.close();
```

right now the code produces the list printed in a straight line in a csv file.
**How do I achieve this format?** Any help will be very appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to do `outFile.print("\n");` before your two line of forEach
"\n" is the character which says "go to the next line"